# How do I use the CSGSI library to interface with Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Game State Integration?

Tags: c#

I download a library called csgis... 
now I want to access a class called

PlayerStateNode

and to access a variable called

```
health
```

... both are public. 
now I made a object and it says that it is does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments... how do I use this then?

code:

```
PlayerStateNode obj = new PlayerStateNode();
int health = obj.Health;
Console.WritelIne(health);
```

Comment: "does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments" is a big clue. There's likely a constructor of factory that you're supposed to use. The library documentation (or digging in to it's code) is the best thing to do here...

Answer (score 1):

See here: https://github.com/rakijah/CSGSI#usage

There is a section "Usage" that explains you directly how to use the library including a full example.

You cannot actively create the objects in the library. Instead, you install an event handler that will be called by the library whenever the state of the game changes. The event handler is passed an object that represents the game state including player health etc.

The background is that you cannot actively request the current game state from CS:GO. Instead, CS:GO is configured to send out the current game state to any registered listener when it is running and the game state changes.

So, you firstly need to configure CS:GO to send the game state to your application (create a `gamestate_integration_*.cfg` file as described on the page linked above) and then in your application, you create a `GameStateListener` object and register an event handler with that object.

This event handler is then called each time that CS:GO sends the game state to your application and the current game state at that moment is passed in as a parameter to the event handler.